# AWS- API Gateway creation and modify event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to trigger an AWS lambda function upon the creation/modification of an API in AWS API gateway. Any idea what are the right events to catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, API Gateway does not generate events directly. Additionally, it does not appear that you can configure an event rule based on CloudTrail logs for API Gateway either. I'll make sure to forward your request to the CloudWatch Events team as a feature request.

Comment: Thanks Bob. As API can be created with cloudformation, we have use cases to trigger lamba upon the successful creation..

Comment: Btw, Bob, if our architecture is to have microservices in Lambda with Gateway APIs in front. Service registration ideally should happen upon the creation of the Gateway API. Due to the unavailability of the events, any workaround suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no event rule of AWS APIGateway in AWS CloudWatch and it does not appear log in AWS CloudTrail, so we can not achieve it now.

Comment: can u be more specific? Are you saying to to set CloudTrail event as a trigger for Lambda function? If yes, what is the 'Event Name' for API Gateway API creation?